# Can I include web.release.config.transform in my NuGet package?

Tags: web-config, nuget, web-config-transform, slowcheetah

We're using SlowCheetah config transforms to manage configuration, so in each of my web apps I have:

```
> Web.config
  >  Web.debug.config
  >  Web.release.config
```

I want to include an appSetting transform element in a NuGet package that will be added to the Web.release.config file when the package is installed (and then *applied* when the project is actually packaged in Release mode)

Following the approach used to transform the actual `web.config` file by using a `web.config.transform` file, I've tried adding a `NuGet\Content\web.release.config.transform` file to my NuGet package that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
 <appSettings>
  <add key="apiUsername" value="my_user" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  <add key="apiPassword" value="my_pass" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Doesn't work. The web.config file gets transformed, but the web.*.config files aren't modified:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NewtonSoft.Json (≥ 4.5.7)'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.7'.
Successfully installed ''MyProject.Package 1.0.7409-unstable'.
Successfully added 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.7' to FortKnox.Web.
'web.debug.config' already exists. Skipping...
'web.release.config' already exists. Skipping...
Successfully added 'MyProject.Package 1.0.7409-unstable' to MyThing.Web
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you're using an old version of nuget? From [this thread](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/229) it appears that this issue has been fixed.